# Player de audio com layout personalizado

Tags: html5

Precisava de fazer um player de áudio igual a este, estou refazendo o site em html5. Alguém sabe me dizer se é possível? O cliente não quer nenhuma alteração de layout.

Link para visualização: [Link](http://luciaduraes.com.br/backup/parsifal/)

Comment: Sim, é possível.

Comment: Se quiser fazer do zero: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-customized-html5-audio-player--webdesign-7081 Algo que ja é bem próximo do objetivo: http://scmplayer.net/

Comment: Entendi... Obrigado. Saberia me dizer se existe algum framework para isso?

Comment: Existem players prontos que podem ser personalizados como SCMPlayer que citei, JWPlayer etc... geralmente esses players são simples demais para criar uma framework envolta deles.

Comment: Você só quer saber se é possível?

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas maneiras de fazer.
Caso 1: Utilizando o HTML5 . Obs: Pode não ser suportado em navegadores antigos. O código ficaria assim:

```
 <audio controls>
     <source src="audio/dedinhos.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 </audio>
```

Caso opte por utilizar uma biblioteca JS por exemplo: [soundmanager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)
. Nesse caso basta ler a documentação e escolher os formatos e a maneira de utilizar. Um breve exemplo ficaria assim:

```
    <link href="css/360-player/360player.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- special IE-only canvas fix -->
    <!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="js/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- Apache-licensed animation library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/berniecode-animator.js"></script>

    <!-- the core stuff -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/soundmanager2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/360player.js"></script>
    <link href="css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>JS</h2>
    <div class="ui360"><a href="audio/dedinhos.mp3">Dedinhos</a></div>
    <div class="ui360"><a href="audio/jesus.mp3">Jesus</a></div>   
</body>
```

Espero ter ajudado.